# SQL Server 2008 R2 multiple aggregates on PIVOT

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

My installment schedule data for each customer goes like this (I restricted sample for one customer only):

```
CUST     CONTRACT_NO                           MONTH    PRINCIPAL   MARGIN  INSURANCE

ENDANG   1012204                                 1      3053515     251107  299000
ENDANG   1012204                                 2      3102161     202461  299000
ENDANG   1012204                                 3      3151583     153039  299000
ENDANG   1012204                                 4      3201792     102830  299000
ENDANG   1012204                                 5      3252830      51837  299000
```

I want the pivot result like below:

```
CUST     CONTRACT_NO                   1                                 2                   
                        PRINCIPAL   MARGIN   INSURANCE    PRINCIPAL    MARGIN   INSURANCE
ENDANG   1012204         3053515    251107     299000      3102161     202461      299000
```

Is it possible to have multiple aggregate columns on pivot command?

Comment: What you are asking for is nested table structure. I believe it is not possible with SQL Server. You may need to mange it with front-end logic.

Comment: thanks for your answer. yes i think it can. but im intend to do this in one shot query.